# Visual Studio keeps building Azure Functions v2 C# projets even if no changes was made

Tags: visual-studio, azure-functions

Even with an empty C# project generated with the Visual Studio 2019 new project wizard, Visual Studio keeps building the project when asking to build the solution (Build -> Build Solution) even if no changes was made.

There is no dependencies in the project, other than the default Nuget packages from the template. No changes are involved between two "Build Solution".

I can't understand why Visual Studio thinks it needs to be built when looking at the Build logs (beginning below):

```
Restoring NuGet packages...
To prevent NuGet from restoring packages during build, open the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on the NuGet Package Manager node and uncheck 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build.'
Running restore with 4 concurrent jobs.
Reading project file C:\Users\benjat\source\repos\plop\Main\Alpha\FunctionApp\FunctionApp.csproj.
The restore inputs for 'FunctionApp' have not changed. No further actions are required to complete the restore.
Committing restore...
Assets file has not changed. Skipping assets file writing. Path: C:\Users\benjat\source\repos\plop\Main\Alpha\FunctionApp\obj\project.assets.json
No-Op restore. The cache will not be updated. Path: C:\Users\benjat\source\repos\plop\Main\Alpha\FunctionApp\obj\FunctionApp.csproj.nuget.cache
Restore completed in 15,78 ms for C:\Users\benjat\source\repos\plop\Main\Alpha\FunctionApp\FunctionApp.csproj.

NuGet Config files used:
    C:\Users\benjat\source\repos\plop\Main\Alpha\.nuget\NuGet.Config
    C:\Users\benjat\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config
    C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Offline.config

Feeds used:
    https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\
1>------ Build started: Project: FunctionApp, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>Resolving SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk'...
```

Is that expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it is a bug in Visual Studio which has been fixed 2 days ago (not yet released)

Link to the report: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/862643/vs-164-does-full-build-of-the-azure-functions-proj.html

Comment: Looks promising. Thanks. Let's wait for the fix availability to test & accept the answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is something called project dependencies and it is not only happened in Visual Studio 2019.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xUb7.png)
Just like this.

When one of your project depends on one or more other projects and you build it the other projects that your projects depends on will also begin to be built. Additionally if the dependencies have changed then the projects dependent on them will always be rebuilt.

if you want to skip build any project, you can choose Build -> Configuration Manager,and then cancel what you don't want to build.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the project doesn't have any dependencies, other than the default one from the template and that no changes was made. I don't want to skip the build in the Configuration Manager, as I need it to be built when there is a real change.

Comment: @BenjaminTalmard Microsoft.NETCore.App is the default package in the eyes of Visual Studio but Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions is not. If you don't believe you can try to remove the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions. And if you want to know more details, you can select Tools->Options->Project and solutions->Build and Run, then choose Diagnostic instead of Minimal under 'MSBuild project build output verosity', after that you can see what happened during building.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your point regarding Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions and Microsoft.NETCore.App. My point is still that even with a brand new project, with no single change in the code, Visual Studio think that it should re-build the project every time I'm building the solution. It doesn't do that with other projects (no change => no build). I've updated my question with some Diagnostic logs but I can't find any reason for this behavior in the logs myself.